# Help in Solving the following linear congruence for x. 6x congruence 97 (mod 125)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey can anybody help me solving this question?

$$6x\equiv97\pmod{125}$$

I'm trying to solve it with Euclidian theorem but still not close to the answer.

Comment: I think you meant $\;6x\equiv97\pmod{125}\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio yes you are write.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The solution is $\;\equiv 97\cdot 6^{-1}\pmod{125}\;$ . To find $\;6^{-1}\pmod{125}\;$ , you need a number $\;t\;$ such that $\;6t=1+125k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ . (Further hint: take a close peek to $\;126\;$ ...) . Then it'll be $\;t=6^{-1}\pmod{125}\;$ .

Comment: i came up with the solution-   1 congu 5(15) mod 37.   then 5x congu 8 (mod 37) => 15 (5x) congu 15(8) (mod 37) => 15 (5x) congu 120 (mod 37). now i'm confused what to do because it is not coming up according to the answer. may be the answer is wrong.

Comment: @S.agnihotri Did you understand my answer? Did you try to get that $\;t\;$ there? Did you read the *further hint*?